# Creating a Package with Sencha Cmd for existing code

Tags: extjs, extjs4

My goal is to add some class libraries I wrote for my apps into packages for a better reusing between different apps.

I followed the example as described in the [docs](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/cmd/5.x/cmd_packages/cmd_creating_packages.html) an created a Workspace with

```
sencha -sdk /path/to/ext-4.2.3 generate workspace /MyApp/data
```

in that workspace I created a package with

```
sencha -sdk ext generate package myapp-data-plugins
```

After that I copied the plugins into the `src` folder. Now I tried to build the package with

```
sencha package build
```

but that failed, because sencha tolds me it cannot resolve `Ext.util.Observable`

Weird. But ok, I googled and found the info I should add

```
package.framework=ext
```

to the `sencha.cfg` but I still got the same error.

Can anyone tell me, how I can create packages the right way?

Comment: Can you add the full stack trace? Also, maybe use the "-d" flag to get additional debugging info.